# R: Sum of multiple column subsets

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I want to sum columns (1,2), columns(3,4) and so on.

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  
1   10  10  10  20  10  30  10  40  
2   20  10  20  20  20  30  20  40
```

I want to get a data frame as:

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4 
1   20  30  40  50  
2   30  40  50  60
```

In general, I have a sequence of column indices

```
colSubset1 <- c(seq(from=1, to=totalcols, by=5))
colSubset2 <- c(seq(from=2, to=totalcols, by=5))
```

And want to do something like

```
newdf <- df[colSubset1] + df[colSubset2]
```

Just doing the above results in a "non-numeric argument to binary operator error" (which I am guessing is because of the column names being different?).

EDIT:

```
newdf <- df[colSubset1] + df[colSubset2]
```

This works fine. I forgot to set header=true while reading my data file which resulted in the non-numeric argument error. Thanks!

Comment: What you're trying to do, seems valid; e.g. `iris[1:2] + iris[3:4]`. Could you post sample data, where what you do results in the error you get?

Comment: My apologies -- I am a R beginnner and forgot to set header=true while reading the table. Hence the df[colSubset1] + df[colSubset2] returned an error. I should have realized from the non-numeric argument error. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit the recycling of short vectors for column selection and just add directly. If you `data.frame` is named `df`, then:

```
df[c(TRUE,FALSE)] + df[c(FALSE,TRUE)]
#   x1 x3 x5 x7
# 1 20 30 40 50
# 2 30 40 50 60
```